# How to do multiple passes with awk?

Tags: awk

I work with huge files (gene expression files); each column represents one sample and each row represents the expression of one specific probe.(The same probes are used for each sample). For example,

Sample1

Probe1
Probe2
...
ProbeN

I can have 43000+ probes and >50 samples. Although I could technically use a 2D array, this would not be efficient once I get files with even more samples. Hence, I was thinking about making multiple passes of the same file (new column each time), apply the algorithm for each column, print the result in a separate file.

I tried a rewind function to start over but the program doesn't follow the same instructions.

```
for(i = ARGC; i > ARGIND; i--)
   ARGV[i] = ARGV[i-1]

 ARGC++
 ARGV[ARGIND+1] = FILENAME

 nextfile
```

Do you have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post some sample data along with your desired output.

Comment: and need two sample data as input file.

Answer (score 1):

From a memory-use point of view, this sounds like a job for pipes and shell scripts.  If your awk script takes its input from stdin, writes its output to stdout, and takes the column number as a parameter, you can achieve what you want quite easily.  It would also allow you to work in a loop or in a single command-line with several pipes.

```
cat gene-file.in | awk -f yourscript.awk -v col=1 | awk -f yourscript.awk -v col=2 | awk -f yourscript.awk -v col=3 > gene-file.out
```

.. or ..

```
#!/bin/bash
cp gene-file.in gene-file.tmp.1
for (( col = 1 ; col <= 10 ; col++ )) ; do
  awk -f yourscript.awk -v col=$col gene-file.tmp.1 > gene-file.tmp.2
  mv gene-file.tmp.2 gene-file.tmp.1
done
mv gene-file.tmp.1 gene-file.out
```

Or any number of alternative ways of accomplishing the same thing.
This way of doing thing would be slower, due to more file writes.  But writing a file 50 times or more isn't huge.  Your disc cache will cope well.

Comment: No need to use `cat` with `awk`, it can read the file itself.

Comment: Yes,  that approach was for illustration, the entire first line is a pipe.  See the 2nd example, it uses a filename argument.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thank you very much for your input. I have never used awk in a shell script, and I was wondering if I could ask you additional questions:

Comment: You'll get a faster turnaround just by asking in the usual StackOverflow way.  I'm not online that often any more.  After you've asked a question, post a link to it as a comment here and I'll see it.  You can delete the comment after a day or so.

Comment: I've just done a search for "[awk] shell" and it gave me quite a few useful questions that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I was beaten to the punch, but since I'd already worked this out - here's a example similar to Paul Hicks that will append the contents of each column to a file based on the column name.

```
#!/bin/bash

fieldCnt=$(head -n1 $1 | awk '{print NF}')
cnt=1
while [ $cnt -le $fieldCnt ]
do
    awk 'out==""{out=FILENAME"."v} {print $v >> out} END{close(out)}' v=$cnt $1
    cnt=$((cnt+1))
done
```

If the data filename was `data`, then it would make a `data.1`, `data.2` up to the number of columns in the file.  You'd call it like `myscript data`.  You could add probe work to the body of the awk in the loop (or less messy to put that into a file and use `awk -f awkfile v=$cnt $1` as in Paul Hicks's example)